# how we can fire two actions on single onclick command

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a query, How we can fire two actions on single onclick command? I have no clue about it.
If you would like I can share the code here so it will be more clear what I want to do. Please suggest me: thanks

```
<input type="button" class="btn rounded" 
       value="<%=labels.run%>" 
       onclick=<%=Post.AbsoluteLink.Segments.GetValue(3) %> && "location.href = 'mlsingle.axd'" />
```

Comment: Is this a javasript question?

Comment: What's <%=Post.AbsoluteLink.Segments.GetValue(3) %> && "location.href = 'mlsingle.axd'?

Comment: @PiLHA I am working on ascx page.. So there is no code behind file.

Comment: @Serge This is not a javasript question by the way I am using Handler for this.

Comment: What I actually want that when a user click on this run button. It takes the index value of the posts and save it in the xml file.

Comment: <%=Post.AbsoluteLink.Segments.GetValue(3) %> is the index value of the post and it stores all the information about this particular post store in the xml file.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an anonymous function:

```
onclick="function(){ doSomething1(); doSomething2(); }"
```

such as:

```
onclick="function(){ 
    <%=Post.AbsoluteLink.Segments.GetValue(3) %>;
    location.href = 'mlsingle.axd';
}"
```